# how to add security questions on wp-registration page and validate it

Tags: plugin-development, security, wp-login-form, authentication, validation

I wanted to validate security questions which show's on wp-login page validation is if answers are blank user cant login and if user register with 2 questions and admin change no. question show on login page then validation is if user given all 2 answer which he registered then he login that time not check 3rd question becoz he not registered 3 ques.so, how to add security questions on wp-registration page and after that validate that question on wp-login page

```
    if ( is_array( wp_unslash( $_POST['seq_ques'] ) ) ) {

            foreach ( $_POST['seq_ques'] as $key_ques => $quest ) 
            {
                for($i=1; $i <= count($all_userans); $i++)
                {   
                    if ( wp_unslash( $_POST['seq_ans'] ) ) :
                    foreach ( wp_unslash( $_POST['seq_ans'] ) as $question => $answer ) :
                        for($i=1; $i <= count($all_userans); $i++)
                        {

                            if ( empty( $answer ) ) {
                              unset($_POST['seq_ans'] [$question]); 
                                $empty_answer = true;echo 'empty';// exit();
                            }
                        }
                    endforeach;
            endif;

                    if ( ! array_key_exists( $quest,$all_userans ) ) {
                        //$is_error_question = true;
                        $is_error_answer = true;    $incorrect_answer = true; 
                        echo "array_key_exists";// break;
                    } else
                         {
                            $user_ques[ $question ] = $question ;
                         }

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: I guess you need to store the questions and answers in user meta, probably hashing the answers. Which part of this are you having problems with: adding the fields to the login and registration forms, saving the answers, validating them as part of authentication, something else? It's probably easier to find an existing plugin that does this though and customise it to your needs rather than starting from scratch, as someone will have already figured all of this out for you.

Comment: I am just wanting to if all answer found which user registered then he login validation not check next no. Question which show's on login page.